# How to fix "Factor level duplicated" Error in R heatmaply()?

Tags: r, heatmap, levels

I'm trying to make a heatmap based on that matrix:

```
  1     2     3     4     5     6     7
C  6211  7608  8089 10514  7363  5375  7268
L  2459  2904  2573  3049  2221  1652  2311
N  3173  4213  3025  4324  2864  1524  2363
S    37    74   141    94    68    48    88
W  1223  1259   914  1691   874   607   912
```

I made it by:

```
c1 <- table(kat_data$delay_code, kat_data$DayOfWeek)
c1 <- as.matrix(c1)
c1
```

And now I'm trying to make a heatmap using `heatmaply()`, but I got an error:

> Error in levels<-(*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : factor level [6] is duplicated

Part of the heatmap code below:

```
p<-heatmaply(c1, 
             dendogram = "none", 
             xlab = "", ylab = "", 
             main = "",
             scale = "column", 
             margins =c(60,100,40,20),............
```

What should I do to make it work? I read a lot of questions with that error and I see that I need to provide unique data, but I don't know where and how to do this. 
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert it to `data.frame` and the error would go away as it is a case of duplicated row names which are not allowed in `data.frame`

```
library(heatmaply)
heatmaply(as.data.frame.matrix(table(mtcars[c('cyl', 'vs')])))
```

[image]

Also, to mention that by wrapping with `as.matrix`, the `table` class still remains

```
m1 <- as.matrix(table(mtcars[c('cyl', 'vs')]))
str(m1)
# 'table' int [1:3, 1:2] 1 3 14 10 4 0
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ cyl: chr [1:3] "4" "6" "8"
#  ..$ vs : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
```

and that is creating the issue as the `?heatmaply` suggests the 'x' to be

> x- can either be a heatmapr object, or a numeric matrix Defaults to TRUE unless x contains any NAs.

So, we can convert the `class` to `matrix`

```
class(m1) <- "matrix"
```

Now, it should work

```
heatmaply(m1)
```

---

Note that, either the `table` or `matrix` object can result in a similar error as in the OP's post

```
heatmaply(table(mtcars[c('cyl', 'vs')]))
```

> Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
>         factor level [4] is duplicated

```
heatmaply(as.matrix(table(mtcars[c('cyl', 'vs')])))
```

> Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
>         factor level [4] is duplicated